# IBM Worklight - Does the MBS support HTML5?

Tags: html, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mbs

mobile browser simulator is not recognizing HTML5 elements like input date type, 
placeholder,localstorage,sessionStorage Video tags. Do I need to change any settings?

Comment: Provide an actual code snippet that is not working for you instead of stating unverified stuff. For example, the HTML file from your Worklight application's common folder.

Comment: Those things depend on the browser the simulator is running on.  The same can be said when the application is deployed on devices.  example.. type="date" brings up the date chooser in IOS, in android it does nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML5 support is not a function of the mobile browser simulator, but a function of the browser the mobile browser simulator runs on.
BTW, In Eclipse you can choose to work with an external browser.